# Display product information on hover over image

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel

I want to display product description over image hover similar to [this](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/rooms/bedroom/gallery/a-serene-green-bedroom-pub6781d3b0) . The products are to be linked via cms admin panel and the user sould be adble to click on the image to tag the related products

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use jquery's hover method for this. You can read the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

This can be done without jquery as well using just the css but since you are already using jquery then I think you should go ahead with the hover method.

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as an answer. To me it's more like a helpful comment for the OP about where to start

Comment: Well the question in itself looks like just asking for the help and did not provide any specifics. That is why I answered just to provide one way of doing it. If you want I can remove it and post it in the comment section of the question.